# rails : routes in nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-resources

I use nested resources

```
#route.rb
resources :users do
     resources :posts
end
```

and with

```
#route.rb
match '/:username' => 'users#show', :as => :user
```

I change `/user/id` to `/username`

but, how change `/users/username/posts` to `username/posts` ?

Comment: This is such a common requirement I think it's about time Rails made this possible. There's no reason it has to force `:id` everywhere... this could be configured without complicating the code for 99% of cases.  Unfortunately I doubt you'll get the answer you're looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

:id is really just a reference to they key that will be used to find your object. It doesn't necessarily need to be the integer representation.

Take a look at the [friendly_id](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/) gem to see how slug handling is done and how to tell ActiveRecord to use that instead of the integer it expects by default.

Answer (score 0):

this work with

```
#route.rb
match '/:username/posts' => 'posts#index', :as => :user_posts
```